# A sql function that returns true/false with some data calculations problems

Tags: mysql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to create a function in sql that returns 0 or 1 if the `"totalOrderSum"` is lower than `1000` or higher. The parameters that are going in are `@artNr`, `@orderNr` and `@amount`. The problem is that I have to find the `@artNr` price from another table and get that price * `@amount` and after that I have to get the total `TotalAmount` from one more table and see if `(TotalAmount + (@price * @amount) < 1000)`.

I have some sql code below and I think you know what i want to do with the code.
Many thanks in advance.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Lab2_spAddOrderLine(@artNr INT,@orderNr INT,@amount) RETURNS BIT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
    DECLERE @result BIT, @price INT,@totalPrice
    IF(
         SELECT Price 
         FROM Lab2_Article 
         WHERE ArtNr=@artNr AS @price
         AND WHERE (
                    SELECT TotalAmount 
                    FROM Lab2_CostomOrder 
                    WHERE OrderNr = @orderNr AS @totalPrice 
                    AND WHERE ((@totalPrice +(@price * @amount)) < 1000
                   )
      )
         SET @result = 1
     ELSE
         SET @result = 0
     RETURN @result
 END
```

Comment: could it be the misspelling of `DECLARE` in line 5 that's a problem?

Comment: According to me, Mysql doesn't support schemabinding.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE lab2_addOrderLineProcedure
(
   IN articleNr INT,
   IN orderNr INT,
   IN amount INT,
   OUT result BIT
)
BEGIN
   DECLARE price INT;
   DECLARE totalPrice INT;

   SET price = (SELECT Price FROM Lab2_Article WHERE ArtNr = articleNr);
   SET totalPrice = ((SELECT TotalPrice FROM Lab2_CostomOrder WHERE orderNr = orderNr) + (price * amount));

   IF totalPrice < 1000 THEN
      INSERT INTO Lab2_OrderLine VALUES (articleNr, orderNr, amount);
      SET result = 1;
   ELSE
      SET result = 0;
   END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many errors in your code. Try the following:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION Lab2_spAddOrderLine(`artNr` INT, `orderNr` INT, `amount` int) 
RETURNS BIT
BEGIN
    DECLARE `result` BIT, `price` INT, `totalPrice` INT
    IF(
         SELECT Price 
         FROM Lab2_Article 
         WHERE ArtNr=`artNr` AS @price
         AND (
                SELECT TotalAmount 
                FROM Lab2_CostomOrder 
                WHERE OrderNr = `orderNr` AS `totalPrice` 
                AND ((`totalPrice` +(`price` * `amount`)) < 1000
               )
  )
     SET `result` = 1
 ELSE
     SET `result` = 0
 RETURN `result`
 END;
```

Comment: Thanks I was not that far of :) but I´ll get an error:`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@artNr INT,@orderNr INT,@amount int) RETURNS BIT WITH SCHEMABINDING AS BEGIN ' at line 1`

Comment: try this by removing `@`

Comment: I`am using phpMyAdmin with mySQL maybe the is a other syntacks for the @ and some more code?

Comment: Then why you tag this ques. as SQL SERVER. plz make it correct.

Comment: I`m new here but i think that I only checked the for a mySQL question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ankit and I have made a modification that works now.